# WSO2 adding permanent datasource configuration

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I configured a Postgresql Datasource on WSO2 admin panel but when I restart the WSO2 server, I cannot access the new configuration.

[image: Config]

I tried to configure it in master-datasources.xml file, but nothing has changed. When I restart the server I cannot find the new conf in Datasources in WSO2 admin panel. I want the added configuration be permanent.

WSO2 version 6.4.0

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Did the configuration succeed (are there no error in the log)? Are you not overwriting the configuration at the start? (e. g. in docker)

Comment: @gusto2 yep. Connection was healthy and I received the logs.

Comment: It seems there is identified issue similar to this.  Check whether the github issue is related. https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2772

Comment: @BK. I have the same issue. Did you resolve this issue? Could you please talk with me the solution? Thank you so much.

Comment: @DuongAnh Hi, I resolved the problem with editing master-datasources.xml file.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit your custom-datasources.xml instead of master-datasources.xml. And make sure you have read access to this files when you save them.
Sometimes, we use root access with FTP and we overwrite these files

Comment: If the datasources which added from master-datasources.xml does not appear, then the same will be applied to custom-datasources.xml file as well.

Comment: Not necessary. It can be a permission problem, or a default inside the master-datasources.xml. And it's a bad habit to put custom datasource inside "master-datasources".